# Django csv export objects name

Tags: python, django

I want to export the csv file but outputs the objects names Why? I don't know how can i fix it ?

this is my export results:

```
No     Name     Day     AttTime LeaveTime               
<staffprofile.views.kintaiLog object at 0x7f955bdbd650> <staffprofile.views.kintaiLog   object at 0x7f955bdbd6d0>   <staffprofile.views.kintaiLog object at 0x7f955bdbd710>              
<staffprofile.views.kintaiLog object at 0x7f955bdbd810> <staffprofile.views.kintaiLog object at 0x7f955bdbd8d0> <staffprofile.views.kintaiLog object at 0x7f955bdbd950>               
<staffprofile.views.kintaiLog object at 0x7f955bdbd910> <staffprofile.views.kintaiLog object at s.kintaiLog object at 0x7f955bdbd9d0>   <staffprofile.views.kintaiLog object at 0x7f955bdbda10>
```

but I  want to export  correct results is like this:

```
No      Name    Day AttTime     LeaveTime
1       AA       2014/4/1      11:00    20:00
1       AA       2014/4/3      13:00    None
1       AA       2014/4/4       None    21:09
1       AA       2014/4/9      13:45    23:04
5       BB       2014/5/4      10:10    19:14
6       BB       2014/5/5      10:10    19:14
7       BB       2014/5/6      10:10    19:14
```

but Following code is not correct results：
This is my views.py:

```
class kintaiLog(object):
    def __init__(self, name, day, attTime, leaveTime):
        self.name = name
        self.day = day
        self.attTime = attTime
        self.leaveTime = leaveTime
def dt2s(dtime):
    if dtime is None:
        return "None"
    else:
        return '%02d:%02d:%02d' % (dtime.hour, dtime.minute, dtime.second)

def export_excel(request):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel; charset="Shift_JIS"')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    titles = ["No","name","day","AttTime", "leaveTime"]
    writer.writerow(titles)
    obj_all = attendance.objects.filter(user = 3).values_list('id','user', 'contact_date', 'contact_time').order_by("-contact_date")
    lea = leavework.objects.filter(user =3).values_list('id','user','contact_date','contact_time').order_by('-contact_date')

    name = Staff.objects.filter(id = 3).values_list('user_name')
    row = [kintaiLog(name, i, None, None) for i in range(32)]

    for att in obj_all:
        day = att[2].day
        log = row[day]
        if log.attTime is None:
            log.attTime = att[3]
        elif log.attTime < att[3]:
            log.attTime = att[3]

    for leav in lea:
        day = leav[2].day
        log = row[day]
        if log.leaveTime is None:
            log.leaveTime = leav[3]
        elif log.leaveTime < leav[3]:
            log.leaveTime = leav[3]


    fmt = 'DAY:%02s, NAME:%10s, ATT:%s LV:%s'
    for log in row:
        if (log.attTime is not None) or (log.leaveTime is not None):
            print fmt % log.day, log.name, dt2s(log.attTime), dt2s(log.leaveTime)

        writer.writerow(row)
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here,

```
class kintaiLog(object):
    def __init__(self, name, day, attTime, leaveTime):
        self.name = name
        self.day = day
        self.attTime = attTime
        self.leaveTime = leaveTime
```

You are pushing the instance into your list comprehension not values.

```
row = [kintaiLog(name, i, None, None) for i in range(32)]
```

So it's gives the output object instances.

**Solution:**

```
class kintaiLog(object):
    def __init__(self, name, day, attTime, leaveTime):
        self.name = name
        self.day = day
        self.attTime = attTime
        self.leaveTime = leaveTime

    @property
    def row_data(self, ):
        return (self.name, self.day, self.attTime, self.leaveTime)

row = [kintaiLog(x, i, None, None).row_data for i, x in enumerate(name)]
```

Comment: I don't know how can i to do fix?

Comment: Thanks, I'm was try that but i have the errors is :Exception Type: IndexError
Exception Value: list index out of range of log = row[day]

Comment: `log = row[day]` ?. Why ?

Comment: I don't know IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Why this `for att in obj_all:
day = att[2].day
log = row[day]
if log.attTime is None:
     log.attTime = att[3]
     elif log.attTime < att[3]:
     log.attTime = att[3]` ?

Comment: Because　i have the [0]is id and [1]is name, [2]is day, [3]is att_time and [4]is leave_time

Comment: Your logic is wrong. Please correct your self. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I'm fix it like at:for att in obj_all:
...     day = att[0][1].day
...     log = row[day]
...     if log.attTime is None:
...         log.attTime = att[0][2]
...     elif log.attTime < att[0][2]:
...         log.attTime = att[0][2]  but i have this errors: TypeError: 'long' object is unsubscriptable

Comment: It means 'long' type object treating a array.But it is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

@ dhana , Thanks
I'm was  fix here: that's working now

for log in row:
        if (log.attTime is not None) or (log.leaveTime is not None):
            writer.writerow([log.name, log.day, dt2s(log.attTime), dt2s(log.leaveTime)])